# Container list, I get error in for loop

Tags: c++, list, containers

I want to know why i can't use for loop in this method, im using it in my replace and insert method but in hear I get some error in for loop line.

```
 Contact return(const list<Contact> &listOf, int index) {
    for(list<Contact>::iterator it = listOf.begin(); it != listOf.end(); it++){

    }

    return Contact();   //dummy return. don't know what to do here
 }
```

I would appreciate some help on how to implement the code and what do I have to return?

I mean I know how to check with if statment to get the right object, but I dont know what do i have to do in if statment and what to write in return instead of "Contact();"

Comment: You can't use a keyword as a function name.

Comment: Please clarify the question about "what do I have to return?"

Comment: I mean I know how to check witch on witch index I want to get the object with if. But I don't know what do I have to do in if statemt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a const_iterator for a const list

```
Contact return_function(const list<Contact> &listOf, int index) {
    for(list<Contact>::const_iterator it = listOf.begin(); it != listOf.end(); it++){

    }

    return Contact();   //dummy return
 }
```

Edit. fixed the function name as pointed by others...

Answer (score 1):

You need `const_iterator`, as `listOf` is `const`.

```
Contact return(const list<Contact> &listOf, int index) {
    //         ^^^^^---const container-----<
    //                                     ^
    // const_iterator--vvvvvv because of ->|
    for(list<Contact>::const_iterator it = listOf.begin(); it != listOf.end(); it++){
```

Also, you must rename your function, `return` is a keyword.

Comment: I know I just trnaslate it from my languge :)